# Multiple classes with barely the same name

Tags: html, css

I've got a little question and it seems there's no place on the internet where I can find the answer except here :p

So I've got an `html` page with some `tables`. Thoses `tables` have lines (as usual :p), and in those lines they are some `inputs`.
I want to add a rule in my css file wich have an effect on all those lines. Those lines have an `id` that is barely the same semantic.

Here's my code :

```
<table>
    <tr id="tr_creneau_1">
        <td>
            <input />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_creneau_2">
        <td>
             <input />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr id="tr_logo_1">
       <td>
           <input />
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

At the end I want a css rule who impact all the inputs in the tr_* lines.

Comment: can you not add a separate `class="someclass"` and style based on the class instead?

Comment: In the post title you mention classes, yet in the example 'id' is used. Normally the kind of behaviour you're describing could easily be done with classes (Each tr could have the same class), but you could also create a css for each tr underneath a specific table.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Where are your `<td></td>`s?

Comment: @thirtydot This is just a piece of code I wrote here, I've got the `<td>` in the original html file :)

Comment: Please don't write code "something like" the code you're actually using. Or if you do, at least make sure it makes sense.

Comment: I just wanted to write the structure of the html code the `<td>` weren't relevent here :)

Comment: I will but I have to wait 3 more minutes to do this :p

Comment: It actually caused me problems while I was trying to help you. I copied and pasted your HTML into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and wrote the `tr[id^="tr_"] input` selector minutes before you recieved it in an answer. But, in my demo the selector didn't work due to the invalid HTML. And, I was very confused until I realised why.

Comment: Oh then sorry mate :s Anyway thanks all of you for your time and answers and the next time I'll put the `<td>` :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
tr[id^="tr_"] input
```

But this is a css 3 selector and it doesn't work on all browsers, alternatively you can simply use:

```
tr input
```

or add a class to every row with that id and match that class

Comment: This is exaclty what I wanted thanks a lot! :D I didn't knew there was a selector like this :) I tried doing it with * or something but this works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always add a CSS class to each table row you wish to target. e.g.

```
<table>
    <tr id="tr_creneau_1" class="style-me">
        <td>
            <input />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_creneau_2"  class="style-me">
        <td>
            <input />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="somethingElse">
        no input, so no class needed
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then style as so:

```css
table .style-me input {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This should work good but I think I'll use the @mck89 answer. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: fair enough, though this is likely a more performant (no string matching) and semantic approach

Comment: Oh yeah maybe really don't know wich is the most performant, but thanks again I'll probably use this another time on an other project :p

Comment: No problems, doesn't bother me just pointing this out :) Also, thanks to thirtydot for editing for validity

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
tr[id^="tr_"] { --your css here-- }
```

It will check all of the `tr` tags if their id starts with `tr_`.

If it doesn't need to be at the start of the id attribute, just somewhere random , you can use:

```
tr[id*="tr_"]
```

If above doesn't work I would suggest going for a class based approach.

Comment: Seems mck89 was one step ahead of me :)